# What is Christianity's view of Jew's rejection of Jesus as Messiah?

Tags: life-of-jesus, prophecy, messiah

An article that discuss [why Jews don't believe in Jesus](https://www.aish.com/jw/s/48892792.html) highlights four reasons why Jesus is not the Messiah, these are the following:

1. Jesus did not fulfill the messianic prophecies.
2. Jesus did not embody the personal qualifications of the Messiah.
3. Biblical verses "referring" to Jesus are mistranslations.
4. Jewish belief is based on national revelation.

Since this could be a very long discussion, we may instead skip the last two because these may be subjective, but the first two of these are challenging arguments since these are with Biblical references.

For the first one, the article cites that the Messiah must fulfill the following OUTRIGHT (copied verbatim):

1. Build the Third Temple (Ezekiel 37:26-28).
2. Gather all Jews back to the Land of Israel (Isaiah 43:5-6).
3. Usher in an era of world peace, and end all hatred, oppression, suffering, and disease. As it says: "Nation shall not lift up sword against nation, neither shall man learn war anymore." (Isaiah 2:4)
4. Spread universal knowledge of the God of Israel, which will unite humanity as one. As it says: "God will be King over all the world – on that day, God will be One and His Name will be One" (Zechariah 14:9).

For a Jew, the Christians' argument that these will be fulfilled on "second coming" must be a lame excuse if without sources from the old testament.

For the second one, the article cites that the Messiah must fulfill the following:

1. Must be a Prophet in the days when the land is inhabited by a majority of world Jewry (Targum – Isaiah 11:2; Maimonides – Teshuva 9:2).
2. Must be descendant of David in the father side (Joseph's Jaconiah line is cursed, also he is not Jesus's bloodline. Moreover, Mary's line is not of Solomon.) (Genesis 49:10, Isaiah 11:1, Jeremiah 23:5, 33:17; Ezekiel 34:23-24)
3. The Messiah will lead Moses' laws (Deut. 13:1-4). We know what happened in the New Testament.

As I believe, the Bible is self-consistent. So, what is Christianity's view of Jew's rejection of Jesus as Messiah?

PS:
I included all detail in case the source link goes down. So its length appears to be an attack but that is not my intention.

Comment: Are you here to learn, or are you hear to declare that Christianity has lame explanations?

Comment: I can answer this but it will be too long. Study Dr Michael Brown's videos or articles or debate videos. some articles give detailed explanations of those obj https://www.biblestudying.net/history-of-judaism1.html